# Vb.net Desktop application that accept POST WebHook

Tags: json, vb.net, webhooks

i need to make a desktop application that accept POST request from a website sending info.

i've read that i can achieve it using asp.net but i want to make it for a desktop application, i will use it for a notification system, using no-ip

The idea is: website send an url with some json data containing the info to the no-ip and the application listening to a port accepting the request and read that data...

Is that possible? thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and code for what you've tried so far. Also, since you have an error, please include the full error traceback in the text of the question.

Comment: you can host web applications within other applications using OWIN. But a desktop application on a user's machine is likely to be behind a firewall, so you'll need to open ports etc (and be **very careful** about it). IMHO you'd be better to build a separate asp.net Web API application, let it receive the requests and place them into a data store, and then have the desktop application check regularly for updates (or perhaps you could implement a two-way websocket channel for it to get info from your API, triggered whenever the API receives something from the external site)

Comment: Ok thanks to all, i've read that i can receive POST with data in a winform through HttpListener, i have tried but nothing happen...
I send post http request with some plain text in it with [link](https://reqbin.com/), but the application with an httplistener listening with this prefix http://*:9999/ is receiving nothing